# Running terminal commands from Chrome's Omnibar

Tags: google-chrome, terminal, address-bar

I would like to use Google Chrome's Omnibar to execute terminal commands.
Is there any way to do that?

Edit:
I found that I could add a custom search engine as "terminal://%s". However, there seems no protocol handler for "terminal:".